# The Skill Sales is not assigned to one or more of the given profiles. Please follow instructions carefully

Tags: liveagent

**Create a Sales Skill and Chat Button**

You have a Support button created for you. Now let’s create the Sales skill and chat button we discussed in this unit.

- The Build a Branded Chat project is a prerequisite to this module. You can’t complete the challenges without a basic Live Agent implementation.
- Call the skill “Sales”.
- Assign the skill to the profiles Custom: Support Profile, Standard User, and System Administrator.
- Call the chat button “Sales Button” (the developer name is Sales_Button and is case-sensitive).
- The chat button must be of type chat button (not an automated invitation).
- The chat button must route using the Sales skill.

[image]

**The steps I followed.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it to all profiles. You missed the `Custom: Support Profile`. Assign the Skill to that as well.